# cross compilation of CUPS on ARM under Linux Environment

Tags: printing, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, cups

I am new in embedded systems and I am trying to add a USB printer support in Linux Environment.

I want to cross compile CUPS ver 1.6.2 for ARM board and Linux Kernel ver 2.6.30.

So Can you please share some steps to cross-compile CUPS on Linux.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a build system. Buildroot, Yocto, PTXdist, whichever one you prefer. But don't try to do it manually.

I'm using Buildroot, and it has a package for CUPS.

Comment: Thanks thomas,                                                       But I am now looking for using LPD/LPR protocol for USB printer sharing in our project, As postscript printer can be shared in network using LPD/LPR printing system.                                      And also I strictly instructed by my seniors for not to use CUPS(large footprint). So now we are looking procedure to setup the usb printer such that any computer in network can use it.                                                                So if you know it then please help me out.                          Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, for ptxdist a CUPS package is currently under review, August 2017.